# Wrong controller action in rails form with link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I have a form...

```
= simple_form_for @form, :url => update_path, :method => :put do |form| 
    = form.input_field :name
    = link_to image_tag asset_path("icon.png"), 
      {:controller => 'controller/name', :action => 'delete', :id => some.id}
    = form.submit
```

As in above form I have a link/image/icon, which on click should fire delete action controller, but for some reason it goes to index controller action. Can someone point what's wrong here please?

Comment: Please add controller name instead of delete_path

Comment: sorry, yes I actually have a controller name there - updated the question

Comment: Please add :method => 'delete' like {:controller => 'controller/name', :action => 'delete', :id => some.id, :method => "delete"}
it will be work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a resources routes, the delete action will be defined as the same url as the **update** action (which is accessed using **PUT** or **PATCH** HTTP verbs),
but it is accessed using the **DELETE** HTTP verb

All you need to do is set the link to the update path of your object and use the **DELETE** verb instead:

```
= link_to image_tag("icon.png"), update_path(id: some.id), method: :delete
```

Also, no need for `#asset_path`, I think

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
= link_to image_tag asset_path("icon.png"), 
          {:controller => 'controller_name', :action => 'delete_method_name', :id => some.id}, 
          {:confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete}
```

Issue is that, you need to pass `:method` as `:delete`, `:action` should be the method name of your controller not the HTTP method.